# Error: Content type X has Drupal core comment comment type, but is a comment type itself for the following content types

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I'm using Node Comments module and I get a strange error in Status Report:

Node Comments
Content type Answer has Drupal core comment comment type, but is a comment type itself for the following content types: Forum topic

However, in the content type settings of 'Answer', this setting is disabled:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72686/CommentSettings.png

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you show is the default setting. It is still possible that one of the comment nodes has a comment somewhere. You can use SQL to investigate.

To be sure that no one can create comments, you need to remove the option in the node create form. However, this wont solve the problem with the already created comment.

Comment: you mean in the node table. I could set comments field to 0 (disabled) ? Is that ok ?

Answer (score 2):

In the description under 'Node Type for Comments': "Important: Every content type which is a comment type should have itself as comment type. Also every comment node type should have at least 1 another content type using it."